# Reshaping a dataframe to a new Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape

[image]

Hi, I want to reshape the data frame to the right one.
A, B, C, ... could be the name of a person.

this is my data:
https://www.udrop.com/5YbK/RelationMatrix.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with joined `MultiIndex` in `map`:

```
df1 = df.stack()
df1.index = df1.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.rename_axis('Link').reset_index(name='Value')
```

For better performance is possible use:

```
c = np.tile(df.columns, len(df))
i = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns))
v = np.ravel(df)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Link':c, 'b': i, 'value': v})
df['Link'] = df['Link'].str.cat(df.pop('b'))
```

Comment: thank you it works well. what if we have a LARGE dataset. what should be done to avoid kernel issues?

Comment: @Hadi - Answer was edited.

Comment: For decreasing data, I want to remove AA data and duplicated ones. What should I do? I just want to retain the data above diagonal

Comment: @Hadi - Can you add inout data and expcted ouout in text format?

Comment: I uploaded my data in CSV format above

Comment: @Hadi - I think small data sample - 4 rows, 3 columns in text format with expected ouput. [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)